# My world properties node background is missing

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I've been trying to figure out what i've touched accidentally to make turn the HDRI picture into blank and mushy color whenever i insert one as a node. Please help. I'm very new in blender so i don't know which properties i need to fix to bring it back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *Environment Texture* node.
You're currently using *Image texture* node, which doesn't work right with HDRIs

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :)